# Trello API directions lead me to error every time

Tags: api, curl, trello

I am trying to automate a json export with cURL. I am following their directions found [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/rest-api/automating-exports/)

I am following their directions in step 1 and using this request to start an export

```
curl -X POST 'https://trello.com/1/organizations/{organizationNameOrId}/exports?key={key}&token={token}' --data 'attachments=false'
```

this starts an export and gives me the same output as in their example. then I go to step 2. I use this request just like they say in their directions

```
curl https://trello.com/1/organizations/{orgIdOrName}/exports/{exportId}?key={key}&token={token}
```

but instead of getting the same output as them I get a message that says

```
can't read the state of an export
```

then when I press enter I get

```
[1] random number 
 Done "then a bunch of empty space" + my original request in step 2 minus the token
```

has anyone else ever had this issue? I can't seem to find it anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. they're missing the apostrophes around the url in step 2. it should be

```
curl 'https://trello.com/1/organizations/{orgIdOrName}/exports/{exportId}?key={key}&token={token}'
```